# Return an Object Array from Java to C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have an array of a custom class in Java that contains two String attributes. I call a Java function from C++ via JNI that returns a array of this class. Can anyone show me how I can access this array in the C++ code?

Kind Regards

Comment: Please try something under this [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314) and ask about programming questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CallStaticObjectMethod](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI) follow the link, its a nice article for problem you are looking

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example instead of just linking to an article.

Comment: agree to you bro, but i think when link is doing the job, than it will be just data redundancy to repeat the think.... sorry if my thought opposes yours

Comment: It may be redundant, but it ensures an adequate amount of information is provided and prevents RTFM type answers (not that this is one). It also prevents the answer from becoming useless in the event that the link becomes invalid (it inevitably happens over time).

Comment: @cpburnz got it... :)  i will update the answer properly on getting some free minutes, and will remeber this point in future...